# How to create a Distribtion Kit via the Command Line with CVI/Labview

Tags: distribution, labview, cvi, labwindows

I've got a NI CVI/Labview project that compiles by using the compile.exe command on the commandline. This generates the expected executables and runs fine on the development PC. However I'd also like to create a Distribution Kit for this project **using a commandline command**.

CVI allows me to generate a Distribution Kit through the IDE and I've also stumbled upon code that allows me to use ActiveX interfaces to open projects and create distribution kits. However I'm looking specifically for a commandline option.

If necessary, the corresponding CDS file of the project is available.

Comment: well, if you can create ActiveX interfaces you can write a command line program using them. I am unaware of one that has already been written. It's fairly simple is you start with a .NET Console App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **short answer** is Yes, you can use a command line to create a distribution kit.

The **longer answer** is that you will have to create your own little executable to do that.  LabWindows/CVI distribution kits are completely compatible with Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) technology, therefore, API calls exist within the SDK to do anything you would like regarding that technology.

Here is a link that should get you on the right path.

http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/3212

(*Pay particular note to Tip 3*)

Regards,
Ryyker

Comment: However this would require me to use ActiveX commands, right? Which is what I'm trying to circumvent ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of how to do this without using ActiveX.  I know that you are not the first to express an interest in command line capabilities for building a distribution kit.  We would also greatly benefit from such a feature.  Regards